# Xcode 8 App installation failed on iPhone

Tags: ios, xcode

Haven't used Xcode in a while. But I recently downloaded a project from Github I want to test out and run on my phone but I keep getting the same message.

[image]

I changed the bundle id and it matches my certificate. I also have pod files on this project. And yes I opened it from .workspace. On a different stack question it said to change PRODUCT_BUNDLE_IDENTIFIER field to "org.cocoapods.${PRODUCT_NAME:rfc1034identifier}" which I already tried and I still keep getting the same message.Any other reason this is happening?

Comment: any other way I can fix this?

Answer (score 1):

Is the app currently installed on the device? If so, uninstall the app from the virtual(or actual) device, it should do the trick. If not select a different device (iPhone SE, 7, etc.)

Comment: No, it didn't work. And the bundle Id is different now that I changed it anyway.

Comment: Try deleting derived data and resetting the simulator. If you have any other apps with the same bundle id you should delete them. Good luck!

Comment: I'm trying to run it on my device not the simulator... @JohnOttenlips

Comment: Try changing the bundle id and cert again and check the product name under build settings.